# What is the purpose of Custom Settings related to Connected App?

Tags: connected-apps

I've inherited some half baked managed app and noticed the Custom Settings section under Connected App.

How was this created and what is the use cases for it?

[image]

Custom setting has fields Endpoint_url__c and API_key__c fields...

Comment: I have observed that if the connected app is included in the managed package, then all the custom settings that are included in the package are linked to that connected app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs for [Manage Other Access Settings for a Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage_additional_settings.htm&type=5): (my emphasis)

> The Connected App Detail page provides an overview of access settings assigned to the connected app, including OAuth policies and session policies. From this page, you can click Edit Policies to manage access to the connected app. **You can also manage profiles, permission sets, custom attributes, and custom scopes associated with the connected app**.

So, it would appear that Salesforce has pulled together any other parts of the deployed managed application that may form part of its configuration.

As [Rahul](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335773/what-is-the-purpose-of-custom-settings-related-to-connected-app#comment495939_335773) and [Menachem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/336317/102) have observed, it does so indiscriminately. The custom settings are part of the managed package and are therefore exposed on the Connected App Details page.

I checked an old managed package and found that custom settings that were created long before the concept of a connected app ever existed were still exposed in this way.

It's an administrative convenience section that doesn't necessarily imply the settings are related to the connected app. That said, hopefully that package is consistent enough within its metadata that they settings and connected app are somewhat related to the same application.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same hunch as Rahul's observation, and have replicated those findings with my own managed package.

Any *public* custom setting that is included in the same managed package as the connected app will be displayed in the section circled in the question.

Comment: Interesting observation but that does not explain the *purpose* ;)

Comment: Well, this proves that from the system's perspective there is no direct correlation or purpose per se. The purpose of *your* custom settings is specific to its particular use.